# Location Services will not activate on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, location

I am developing an iOS app which uses Location Services. The app works fine on iPhones (3GS and 4), but does not request locations services when run on the iPad. That is, the user is never asked to enable location services, nor does the app appear in Location Services section of the Settings app.

I have seen a few forum posts describing similar issues, but all of these were resolved by installing the app on the iPad through iTunes (via ad-hoc distribution) rather than running it through Xcode, or by resetting location warnings. I tried both of these solutions on an iPad, an iPad 2, and the iPad simulator, both to no avail.

We use the following code to enable Location Services updates. We have verified both by on-device debugging and placement of `NSLog`s that our code is getting run.

```
- (id)init {
    [super init];

    if (clManager == nil) {
        clManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    clManager.delegate = self;

    [self startLocationMonitoring];

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isLocationAvailable {
    return [CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable];
}

- (void)startLocationMonitoring {
    if ([self isLocationAvailable]) {
        [clManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    } else {
        // handle lack of Location Services
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This probably does not answer your question, but might help somebody. The WiFi iPad models don’t support significant location changes (the `significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable` method returns `NO`) and the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` seems to do nothing when running on these – it does not trigger the error delegate method nor it brings forward the blue bubble dialog asking for location services permission.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was what I needed to know. In my app, I'm using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChange and many iPad wifi and iPod users have reported that the location services is not working properly. I have decided to switch to startMonitoringLocations to support those users in case significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable returns NO. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes this is correct. The iPad 1 WiFi don't support it. I've just been debugging this myself. iPad 1 WiFi+3G do support it. I decided to use startLocationMonitoring and then turn it off again once i receive a location - which was fine for my purpose. Alternatively, you could startLocationMonitoring and use a distanceFilter to specify your own 'significant' location change.

Answer (score 0):

iPad comes in 2 models (wifi and wifi+3G). http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/

The wifi model does not have A-GPS support.

If yo go through the specification you will see that A-GPS is only available on wifi+3G model and perhaps you are using the wifi(only) model.

However, through WIFI, iPad can detect locations if router is providing the same which does not seems to be in your case.

You can try your app on iPad2 wifi+3G version and you will see that it runs just fine..!!